# How can I determine when control key is held down during button click

Tags: c#, windows

How can I determine when the control key is held down during button click in a C# Windows program? I want one action to take place for Ctrl/Click and a different one for Click.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

And a little bit more:

```
private void button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{           
    if( (ModifierKeys  & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control )
    {
        ControlClickMethod();    
    }
    else
    {
        ClickMethod();
    }
}

private void ControlClickMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show( "Control is pressed" );
}

private void ClickMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show ( "Control is not pressed" );
}
```

Comment: I feel really stupid.  I had no idea that ModifierKeys existed.  I've been doing it old school (capturing the keydown and setting a boolean) for years.  I guess you do learn something new every day.  :)

Comment: I feel "stupid" everyday...and definitely every time I come on StackOverflow, then I get inspired by the "smart" developers and strife to better myself. (This is in no way an agreement with you being "stupid" by the way")

Comment: Thank you very much, Simon. Works perfectly! I voted you up but where did the "Accept Answer" link go!

Comment: I believe you should see a tick mark to click if you own the question?

Comment: Got it. Thank you again, very much. I googled the crap out of this and then you answered me in a matter of minutes. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming WinForms, use Control.ModifierKeys, eg:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(Control.ModifierKeys.ToString());
}
```

Assuming WPF, use Keyboard.Modifiers, eg:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(Keyboard.Modifiers.ToString());
}
```